# Why does the iteration terminate at 995 in this python code? Problem 4 project euler

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to attempt Problem 4 of the Euler Project:
A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.

Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.
My iterations seem to stop at 995

```
for i in range(100,1000):
    for a in range(100,1000):
        prod=i*a
        strp=str(prod)
        if(strp[::-1]==strp):
            print(i,a,prod)
```

Comment: Why do you use `a += 1`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I've edited it now.

Comment: If you edit the code in the question and it works now, this invalidates the answers and makes the question pointless.

Comment: *"iterations seem to stop at 995"*: what makes you think that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iteration doesn't terminate there. It terminates at 999 999, as expected. Your `print` statement is conditional: you only print when you have a palindrome!

I might suggest changing that second `for` loop to

```
for a in range(i, 1000)
```

to avoid repeating combinations you've already considered.

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing `a`, while using it as your iterated variable in the for loop.

Remove `a += 1`, as `for a in range(100, 1000):` automatically increments `a` within the loop.

Edit: This didn't fix the 'problem', but it seems like the loop itself is not terminating after 995 iterations, but instead the `if` statement stops evaluating to `True`, meaning no more printing. However, the loop itself is running correctly.

Comment: Yeah, it was a mistake. But that doesn't seem to be fixing the problem.

Comment: Running the code myself, the loop doesn't **stop** at 995, your if statement just stops evaluating to True, so the printing stops.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're printing the variable only when you get a palindrome, hence it stops at 995.
2. Since you need the largest palindrome, the wise approach would be to run the loop in reverse, to test the bigger numbers first.
3. Start `a` with `i` rather than `999`, to avoid testing duplicates.

```
for i in range(999,99,-1):
    for a in range(i,99,-1):
        prod=i*a
        strp=str(prod)
        if(strp[::-1]==strp):
            print(i,a,prod)
            break
```